# Avoid index url after failing create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

When you create a User in rails through the create action, the url is changed to

```
http://myapplication.com/users with POST
```

before being redirected elsewhere. If validation fails, it appears that the above URL is retained. If you then refresh, you end up on the index page (as it's now a GET).

I would expect if validation was failed the url would remain as

```
http://myapplication.com/users/new
```

As i don't have an index page, this is causing me problems. Is there a way to resolve this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the logic in the `respond_to` block in your controller.

This is a typical example of the *create* action in `users_controller.rb`:

```
 def create
   @user = User.new(params[:user])

   respond_to do |format|
     if @user.save
       format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
       format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
     else
       format.html { render action: "new" }
       format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
 end
```

So if the save fails, the `new` action is rendered again.

Comment: How does this solve the question? render(:new) will keep the url as /users, causing the 404 when refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

In your UsersController, do like this:

```
def new
 @user =  User.new
end

def create
 @user = User.new(params[:user])

 if @user.save
   redirect_to root_url # save success will return to root page
 else
   render 'new'
 end
end
```